# Allow user to select which registration type on Entity Registration module

Tags: entities, users

H, I am using the Entity Registration module, but I would like the user to be able to select what kind of registration type - e.g. registering as a participant, a facilitator or a resource-provider. 
Is this possible? as it seems as though its only possible to enable one registration type on a registration field.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use the Entity Regisration module for registration but for my suggestion. You should use the [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module for that purpose. It allows you to:
- Create many type of user profiles
- The link for registration of each kind of users (Must use the [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module)
- The custom fields for each kind of users

Comment: entity registration allows users to sign up for any kind of entity- it is not to do with registering on the website.

Comment: Oh ! I misunderstood. So i thought you want to create many roles: registering as a participant, a facilitator or a resource-provider. And guests come to website and register for that kind of users.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you should be able to define several registration types. On your event (content type) if you specify a field type as registration, the widget will allow the person defining the event to select which type of registration is required.

Based on your description though, I believe you only need one registration form  with a select list field to allow them to indicate his role in the event.

So for Registration type event_registration you will need to define a field called type_of_registration with a select list field that contains 3 types, participant, facilitator  or resource provider